# jQuery: How to stop the change() event from firing from the blur() handler?

Tags: jquery

I have the following scenario:

```
$("#element").blur(validate).change(onElementChange);
```

The validate() function should prevent the change event from firing, if the value of the #element is not valid. 
I cannot add the validate to change, because it needs to validate on blur too. 
If add the validate() to both events, the alert with the validation error will pop up twice.

So, the my question is, can I stop the change event from firing from the handler of the blur event?

Also if you have a different solution (without using plugins), i would like to hear it.

Thanks

Comment: What about using only a `blur` handler and calling your `onElementChange` from inside `validate` programmatically? This would allow your blur handler to control the execution of `onElementChange` like you describe.

Comment: you have an alert with the validation error? users won't like that, alerts are a bit too intrusive.

Comment: @Jimmy Cuadra: yes, that would solve the problem with the double call, but unfortunately the onElementChange does some updates which should be made only if the data is modified.


@Ed Woodcock: I am aware of that, but this application is only for internal use, so no problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround to the problem:

- handling the validation only after the change event
- triggering the change event in the handler or the blur (in case)

Answer (score 0):

can't you call the onElementChange function inside your validate function when it returns valid.

Comment: unfortunately the onElementChange does some updates which should be made only if the data is modified.